# wp_verify_nonce doesn't return true on server when it matches the nonce

Tags: ajax, nonce

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
            action: "more_news",
            nonce: nonce,
            offset: offset
    },
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log( nonce );
        console.log( data );
        console.log( textStatus );
    }
});
```

Checking for this AJAX request nonce locally works perfectly. As seen below, my console prints my nonce, "Awesome", and then "success".

```
9a91a5fdca
Awesome
success
```

When on my server, my console prints my nonce TWICE (thus proving to me they're exactly the same), then success.

```
e2ca4eca80
e2ca4eca80
success
```

I'm… confused… to say the least. How is this possible? and how do I solve it?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_more_news', 'more_news' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_more_news', 'more_news' );

function more_news(){
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'more_news_nonce') ){
        exit($_POST['nonce']);
    }
    echo 'Awesome';
    die();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code used to create your nonce?

Comment: this inexplicably has started working on the server. caching issue? apache bug? I'm not sure what happened, but it's working now

Comment: @zack I faced the issue previously. It was because of the cache issue. Make sure you have set an interval to clear your cache,

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter for `wp_verify_nonce()` is the action. That part is not in your question, but I guess it should be called like:

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], $_POST['action']) ){
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't action be the same as you sent?

```
    data: {
        action: "more_news",
        ...

   function more_news(){
      if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'more_news_nonce') ){
      ....
```

I assume it should be

```
   function more_news(){
      if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'more_news') ){
      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be,

```
 data: {
        action: "more_news",
        nonce: <?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'saiful_create_nonce' ); ?>,
        offset: offset
},
```

and wp function

```
function more_news(){
  if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'saiful_create_nonce', 'nonce' ) ){
    return false;
  }
 echo 'Awesome';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ensuring you use the same [action](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/#creating-a-nonce-for-use-in-some-other-way) key to create and validate your nonce, you also need to keep in mind that ajax/wp_rest requests to the server does not authenticate logged in users, see the following [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/),

> For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to wp_rest. These can then be passed to the API via the _wpnonce data parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via the X-WP-Nonce header. If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re logged into WordPress.

you can remedy this by simply adding a nonce to your request,

either in your AJAX header,

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/uid',
  method: 'GET',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', settings.nonce);
  }
})
```

or using a hidden field in your form,

```php
$_wpnonce = wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );
echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = '_wpnonce' value = '$_wpnonce' />";
```

when a nonce is created, it uses the current logged-in user ID to make the nonce unique to that user and as such the same [user ID needs to be identified to verify the nonce](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_verify_nonce/#source).

At page load and nonce creation, the logged user is identified, however if your request is done via Ajax or wp_rest API, then the user is no longer authenticated, unless the `_wpnonce` is submitted for the action `wp_rest`.  So this could also be the issue with the nonce verification failing.